# I want to make db with text type column. but length is always 0 . in mysql

Tags: mysql, text, sql-types

I make db table in mysql.

```
create table finaltest1(id int(10),title text(20), category text(20), price text(10), ymd text(15), iconurl text(50), screenshoturl text(150), appid text(15), company text(30), capacity text(15));
```

but text column's length is all 0. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As swati has already said, you need to learn the [MySQL String Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-types.html). If you use TinyText, the column will always take up 256 bytes, even if it's empty. You should note that with the *Text column types you cannot have default values.

If you use a VARCHAR(20) column, the actual data space used depends on the contents, and you can have defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If you want limited text with field then use datatype VARCHAR (20) . Else for long text use simply TEXT datatype .

check : http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php

The length given by you 20 is comes under the TINYTEXT .

```
TINYTEXT    256 bytes    
TEXT        65,535 bytes            ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT  16,777,215 bytes        ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes     ~4GB
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` doesn't need a length. Learn more from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html).
The following query should work.

```
create table finaltest1(id int(10),
    title text,
    category text,
    price text,
    ymd text,
    iconurl text,
    screenshoturl text,
    appid text,
    company text,
    capacity text
);
```